# how to update openssl on windows 10 ubuntu subsystem

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssl

I have Ubuntu running on my windows 10 box.  I'm trying to update openssl to latest.  (specifically I need to install 1.1.1m)

This is what I've tried so far:

```
admin@mymachine:/mnt/c/Users/me$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install openssl
[sudo] password for admin:
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1310 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [228 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9732 B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [799 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [114 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [681 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [122 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [909 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [202 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [20.2 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [23.8 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [580 B]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [22.7 kB]
Fetched 7726 kB in 8s (910 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
14 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  openssl
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 621 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 openssl amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.11 [621 kB]
Fetched 621 kB in 1s (512 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 38996 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.11) over (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10) ...
Setting up openssl (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

But as you can see it just set up 1.1.1f again.

```
admin@mymachine:/mnt/c/Users/me$ openssl
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
OpenSSL>
```

This is the version of Ubuntu I have:

```
admin@mymachine:/mnt/c/Users/me$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

I found this article: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/linux/upgrade-openssl-on-ubuntu-20/

But before I dive in, I was wondering if there's another way to do this / if this is the way to go for Windows subsystems.

Please and thanks.

**Edit 1**

Related to this question would be how I update Ubuntu itself?
I tried this:

```
admin@mymachine:/mnt/c/Users/me$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

But it's not clear to me what the difference is between development version and non-LTS development version.  Googling but if you have any tips on this approach please feel free to comment.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any need for the latest version? If not, don't do it. Otherwise the difference between LTS and non LTS version is described here -> https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Comment: @paladin the only thing i really need to do is upgrade openssl to 1.1.1m, per our corporate policy

Comment: It's possible to manually update individual packages but please take note that when doing so, you have to take care for the entire lifecycle of the package, until you change from ubuntu 20.04 LTS to any ubuntu version which has at least your desired openssl version. I don't think this would be a problem for openssl, as this is a relative small library, but take note that unforseen incompatibilities might be possible in future, which might turn off openssl functionality on your system.

Comment: Your corporate policy should be updated to be compatible with Ubuntu. Generally, Ubuntu patches vulnerabilities instead of bumping to a higher upstream version. If you MUST bump to a higher upstream version, you will find Ubuntu to be frustrating since you won't be using it as designed.

Comment: A cheap workaround would be to use *debian unstable* instead of ubuntu LTS. Or you might use regular ubuntu (non LTS) but this needs more maintenance than *debian unstable*. (Ubuntu is a derivat from *debian unstable*)

Comment: Important - [Please see How do I install Ubuntu 21.10 in WSL on Windows 11?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1369637/1165986) for special instructions for doing this on WSL.  Mainly, you need to uninstall the snapd package before upgrading.