# Cant install podman in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, podman

Although the podman documentation indicates i should be able to install it into an ubuntu 20.04, i cant:

```
sudo apt-get install podman
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libevent-dev libevent-extra-2.1-7 libevent-openssl-2.1-7 libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc15 libpmix2
  libpsm-infinipath1 libpsm2-2 libwireshark13 libwiretap10 libwsutil11 libxnvctrl0 libyajl2
  linux-headers-5.4.0-125 linux-headers-5.4.0-125-generic linux-image-5.4.0-125-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-125-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-125-generic ocl-icd-libopencl1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  catatonit conmon containernetworking-plugins dns-root-data dnsmasq-base fuse-overlayfs fuse3 libfuse3-3
  podman-machine-cni podman-plugins slirp4netns
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fuse
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  catatonit conmon containernetworking-plugins dns-root-data dnsmasq-base fuse-overlayfs fuse3 libfuse3-3 podman
  podman-machine-cni podman-plugins slirp4netns
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 1 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 2937 kB/30.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 148 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 https://provo-mirror.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_20.04  podman-plugins 100:1.2.0-1 [1116 kB]
Err:1 https://provo-mirror.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_20.04  podman-plugins 100:1.2.0-1
  File has unexpected size (1034528 != 1116320). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.193.113.70 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:49e09a6ff2b0b827ddc0d830edd160b4ec03875a3f8c8195bfd53b7867fd0b22
   - SHA1:44470e9d5c4b64f1602d3a82f1b28e400e16796c [weak]
   - MD5Sum:d5cc530c789e0fc256ecc02603ff9685 [weak]
   - Filesize:1116320 [weak]
Get:2 https://provo-mirror.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_20.04  podman-machine-cni 100:0.0.0-1 [1821 kB]
Err:2 https://provo-mirror.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_20.04  podman-machine-cni 100:0.0.0-1
  File has unexpected size (1639592 != 1820908). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.193.113.70 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:a55aece52bf91eca31468c2ee3fda0dd8747d9619e6d327731ab9336c5e73185
   - SHA1:04d302c1f0143f8f2c4f7244a3d58e8e5a4f222e [weak]
   - MD5Sum:7972b09bf0a15658d711d55f5f295b45 [weak]
   - Filesize:1820908 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://provo-mirror.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/podman-plugins_1.2.0-1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (1034528 != 1116320). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.193.113.70 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:49e09a6ff2b0b827ddc0d830edd160b4ec03875a3f8c8195bfd53b7867fd0b22
    - SHA1:44470e9d5c4b64f1602d3a82f1b28e400e16796c [weak]
    - MD5Sum:d5cc530c789e0fc256ecc02603ff9685 [weak]
    - Filesize:1116320 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://provo-mirror.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/podman-machine-cni_0.0.0-1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (1639592 != 1820908). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.193.113.70 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:a55aece52bf91eca31468c2ee3fda0dd8747d9619e6d327731ab9336c5e73185
    - SHA1:04d302c1f0143f8f2c4f7244a3d58e8e5a4f222e [weak]
    - MD5Sum:7972b09bf0a15658d711d55f5f295b45 [weak]
    - Filesize:1820908 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried sudo apt-get update --fix-missing, also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296657/unable-to-install-podman-in-ubuntu-20-04-running-on-wsl2-in-windows-10), [this](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-podman-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa/) and [this](https://podman.io/docs/installation) and the result is the same.

I also opened up [this issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/20067) but im not sure if the problem is with podman, ubuntu or myself.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes "Failed to fetch ... File has unexpected size. Mirror sync progress?" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182803/what-causes-failed-to-fetch-file-has-unexpected-size-mirror-sync-progress)

Comment: Kinda. Turns out its not in the repo, so we ended up using other links in /etc/apt/sources.list.d.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had an unstable repo in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d:

https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/unstable/xUbuntu_22.04/

Im also used a version of crun that conflicted with that actually used by podman. Removing it from /etc/apt/sources.list.d, calling apt-update and removing and reinstalling podman slved the issue.